# Given the recurrence $T_n = 5T_{n-1} - 6T_{n-2}$ ,Prove by induction $T_n = 3^n - 2^n$ is the solution.

Tags: induction

Given : $ T_0 = 0 $ , $T_1 = 1$ 
Base case : 
 $T_2 = 5T_1 - 6T_0 = 5  =  3^2 - 2^2$ 
$T_3 = 5T_2 - 6T_1 = 19  =  3^3 - 2^3$ 
Assumption : 
$T_n = 3^n - 2^n$ &  $T_{n-1} = 3^{n-1} - 2^{n-1}$ 
To prove :
  $T_{n+1} = 3^{n+1} - 2^{n+1}$ 
 $T_{n+1} = 5T_n - 6T_{n-1}$ 
$ = 5(3^n - 2^n) - 6(3^{n-1} - 2^{n-1})$ 
$ = 5(3^n - 2^n) - 2.3^{n} + 3. 2^{n}$ 
$ = 3^n(5-2) - 2^n(5-3)$ 
$ = 3^n.3 - 2^n.2$ 
$ = 3^{n+1} - 2^{n+1}$ 
Hence , $T_n = 3^n - 2^n$  is the solution of the given recurrence. 
I just wanted to know if my approach is correct or is there any other way to solve it? Thankyou.

Comment: Lookin' good to me!

Comment: [See Wikipedia about solving recurrence relations. You can use a characteristic polynomial.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving)

Comment: Yes this is correct. Your base case could also, maybe more simply, be $T_0=0$, $T_1=1$.

Comment: @Did Your suggestion to start with $T_0$ and $T_1$ is not just a simplification but a correction. An induction using $T_2$ and $T_3$ as the basis proves the result only for $n\geq2$. So the OP's proof would have to be supplemented with checking $T_0$ and $T_1$ in order to cover all relevant values of $n$.